# Are the first two episodes of season 4 of Bojack Horseman borrowing plots from films?

Tags: reference, bojack-horseman

I just watched the first two episodes of season 4 of [*BoJack Horseman* (TV Series 2014–)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3398228/), and the plots seemed very elaborate, specific, and only including the series' characters in a plug-in fashion.

I know that adult comic cartoons have a habit of making episodes that borrow plots from films for some reason - is that what's responsible for much of the storyline in these?

And if so, what are they referencing?

One seems like a juvenile silly comedy where someone runs for political office and ends up getting to ski race for it.

The other is some weird, nostalgic, Michigan, old family home with ghosts from 1944 whose son dies in the war, mom goes crazy with grief and has her daughter drive a car because mom is drunk, mom gets given a lobotomy... mixed with a neighbor who also lost his wife and is psychologically stuck and helps the visiting character fix his old family home.

Answer (score 2):

The ski race reminded me of a John Cusack movie [Better Off Dead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Better_Off_Dead_(film)#Plot)

John Cusack plays the role of Lane, who is dealing with Roy, captain of the ski team and bully as he begins an interesting friendship with Monique, the French foreign exchange student.

> When Roy insults Monique, Lane challenges him to a ski race down the K-12, with the winner to be captain of the ski team.

However, the second episode I've not been able to place yet.  Does seem oddly familiar...